# Is there a way to stream RTSP audio stream only to stdout with ffmpeg

Tags: python, go, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have a webcam that stream the video/audio via rtsp. I wish to make a small program that only detect the audio stream and make a room loudness detection.

My plan is to use `ffmpeg` to get the audio stream only as a stream of integer/float to stdout. So that I can read the stream in Python or Go as callback and analyse and decibles.

I found an example:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://some_url -c:a aac -c:v copy -hls_list_size 65535 -hls_time 2 "./live.m3u8"`

But this write the whole video to files. Any suggestion how to change that?

I am also open to any other solution/packages in other languages that I can do something like

```
connection = RTSP('rtsp://url')
signal_array = connection.read_audio_frame()
```

Please advice

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/322216/how-can-i-pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-to-ffplay

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg can be made to output to stdout by adding `pipe:`.  Per the docs:

> The accepted syntax is:
>
> ```
> pipe:[number]
> ```
>
> number is the number corresponding to the file descriptor of the pipe (e.g. 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr). If number is not specified, by default the stdout file descriptor will be used for writing, stdin for reading.

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#pipe

Personally I would use this in conjunction with a named pipe (FIFO):

```sh
mkfifo /tmp/videofifo
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -f avi pipe: > /tmp/videofifo
```

```py
with open("/tmp/videofifo", "rb") as f:
    ...
```

Of course, for your use case, you use your ffmpeg command, and you open the fifo in `"r"` not `"rb"` mode.

The advantage of using a fifo over just capturing stdout (with `subprocess.PIPE` directly is probably minimal in your case (ascii data linewise) but seems cleaner in the case of binary data.  In any case I prefer to keep the data separate from how I got it.  If you do just want to handle stdout directly, use `p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` and then work on `p.stdout`, which is a file-like object.

Doubtless there are equivalent ways to launch subprocesses in Go, but to my shame I don't actually know Go at all at the moment.